# Android NDK #define Problems

Tags: android, android-ndk, c-preprocessor

When I add #define to either main.cpp or one of my headers called from main.cpp, it does not seem to be defined in other files.

For example, in main.cpp I might do something like:

```
#define TEST_FOO 1
```

Then in one of my other files, for example secondfile.cpp, TEST_FOO is ignored as if it was never defined:

```
#if TEST_FOO
// do something <- this never gets reached
#endif
```

Even if in the Android.mk file I place secondfile.cpp after main.cpp:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp \
                   secondfile.cpp
```

Is there a way to #define values in Android NDK inside the actual code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is correct. The compiler only knows about one source file at a time. When you compile `secondfile.cpp`, it has completely forgotten about anything you may have defined in `main.cpp`.

If you want a `#define` to be visible in all your source files, you need to put it in a header which is included by all your files. Or, pass it on the command line; you can do this by adding something like this to your `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -DTEST_FOO=1
```

Comment: Using multiple libraries `APP_CPPFLAGS += -DTEST_FOO=1` in Application.mk works aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the header file and include the header file in every .c file where you want it to be defined.